# Flask: remove end of line characters from url

Tags: python, flask

i need to remove the end of line characters from incoming requests in flask. If the route is `https://localhost/test\r\n` I need to remove `\r\n`. This is due to an issue from a oher program, that is alwas sending these. So is there a way to make this neater?

```
@app.route("/test")
@app.route("/test\r\n")
def test():
    return "TEST"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use middleware to solve the issue, as you can wrap your application and modify input and output before the application.

Here is a working example of such:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


class PathNormaliser:
    """
    Simple WSGI middleware
    """
    def __init__(self, app):
        self._app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'].replace("\\r", "").replace("\\n", "")
        environ['REQUEST_URI'] = environ['REQUEST_URI'].replace("\\r", "").replace("\\n", "")
        environ['RAW_URI'] = environ['RAW_URI'].replace("\\r", "").replace("\\n", "")
        return self._app(environ, start_response)


app.wsgi_app = PathNormaliser(app.wsgi_app)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"


app.run()
```

You can read more about it in a thread similiar to your case here: [modify flask url before routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652067/modify-flask-url-before-routing/44652193#44652193)

Or alternatively, you can read about WSGI middleware here:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=middleware#flask.Flask.wsgi_app

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a simple WSGI middleware that fixes the URL before
they are processed by Flask. That might look something like:

```
from flask import Flask


class FixURLMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ["PATH_INFO"] = environ["PATH_INFO"].strip()
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = FixURLMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)


@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello, world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

For any incoming request, this will call the `strip()` method (which
removes whitespace, including newlines and carriage returns, from the
start and end of strings) on the path before the request is handled by
Flask.

Comment: You can not use `.strip()` as `\n` is escape (`\\n`) in `PATH_INFO`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743069/678611 solution

Comment: You and I have different readings of the question. I think it contains a newline and carriage return, in which case `strip` is correct. If it instead contains the literal string `\r\n`, then use e.g. `replace` instead. The general solution remains the same.

Comment: You're right if you need to remove `\r` and `\n` and not `\\r` and `\\n`, but Flash escapes `\n` and `\r` so `strip()` does not work.